# How to switch pages using the VueJS router in the Electron protocol?

Tags: vue.js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTzKq.png

Like this picture, I am using a Electron to make a browser. I use VueJS, Vue router. Now I want to implement chrome://version/ such as Chrome browser.

I have read the electron [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol) for a long time, but still can't complete this function, I tried to register registerHttpProtocol, my index.html was sent as html to webview, and my js also sent the same content as index.html

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import constant from '../../constant';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: __dirname,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'browser',
      component: require('@/components/BrowserPage').default,
      meta: {
        title: constant.config.productName,
        icon: 'static/icon/browser.png',
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/browser',
      name: 'private',
      component: require('@/components/PrivatePage').default,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'setting',
          component: require(/* webpackChunkName: "setting" */'@/components/PrivatePage/Setting').default,
          meta: {
            title: '设置',
            icon: 'static/icon/setting.png',
          },
        },
      ],
      meta: {
        title: 'Loading...',
        icon: 'static/icon/loading.png',
      },
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/',
    },
  ],
});
```

Normal should be

address #### actual address

```
browser://index  #### file://${__dirname}/index.html

browser://setting #### file://${__dirname}/index.html#/setting

browser://bookmark #### file://${__dirname}/index.html#/bookmark

browser://history #### file://${__dirname}/index.html#/history

browser://index/css/style.css #### file://${__dirname}/css/style.css

browser://index/js/vender.js #### file://${__dirname}/js/vender.js

browser://index/images/login.png #### file://${__dirname}/images/login.png
```

Actually the address is

address #### actual address

```
browser://index  #### file://${__dirname}/index.html

browser://setting #### file://${__dirname}/index.html

browser://bookmark #### file://${__dirname}/index.html

browser://history #### file://${__dirname}/index.html

browser://index/css/style.css #### file://${__dirname}/index.html

browser://index/js/vender.js #### file://${__dirname}/index.html

browser://index/images/login.png #### file://${__dirname}/index.html
```

## There may be two cases for the address

```js
const winURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? 'http://localhost:9080/index.html'
  : `file://${__dirname}/index.html`;
```

How can I implement this function normally? How to combine elelctron protocol and vue router and let static resources load properly?

Answer (score 0):

How about importing the router.js and using the `push` method?

Something like this:

```js
import router from './router.js';

router.push('/myroute');
```